# Parsing a macro argument character-by-character for conditional execution

Tags: macros, conditionals, chess

In an attempt to specify a seemingly endless amount of arguments to a macro, I would like to supply only one `#1`, where `#1` is a string that contains a bunch of *specific* characters. For example

```
\mymacro{1jq4PK2/62Bb/-krkR/...}
```

Then, I'd like to sequentially parse `#1` on a character-by-character basis and do something based on the character. As in the example above, characters could be anything from numbers `0...9`, letters `a...z` and `A...Z` (so conditioning should be case sensitive) or symbols `-`,`/`,...

The bigger picture here is create a macro that uses [`chessfss`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chessfss) to typeset a chess board or arbitrary shape using [FEN notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation). The symbol `-` will denote a blank square, numbers will denote empty squares (with no piece on it), `/` will denote the next rank, and letters will denote the colour (via capitalization) and type (via the specific letter) of the piece.

The code provided by the [`skak` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/skak) is limited to a fixed 8-rank (or file) chess board. Specifically, `skak` provides `\InitBoard` that is defined as

```
\def\InitBoard(#1/#2/#3/#4/#5/#6/#7/#8){%
  %<code>
}
```

where each one of the 8 arguments is processed in a very "nested fashion" using (I'm skipping some intermediate steps for the sake of brevity):

```
\def\FenConvert#1{%
  \EqStr{8}{#1}%
  {EEEEEEEE}%
  {\EqStr{7}{#1}%
    {EEEEEEE}%
    {\EqStr{6}{#1}%
      {EEEEEE}%
      {\EqStr{5}{#1}%
        {EEEEE}%
        {\EqStr{4}{#1}%
          {EEEE}%
          {\EqStr{3}{#1}%
            {EEE}%
            {\EqStr{2}{#1}%
              {EE}%
              {\EqStr{1}{#1}%
                {E}%
                {#1}}}}}}}}}

\def\ParseFenRank#1{\ParseFenRankA(#1Z)}
\def\ParseFenRankA(#1#2){%
  \EqStr{Z}{#1}%
  {}%
  {\FenConvert{#1}\ParseFenRankA(#2)}}
```

I would like to steer clear from this since it is not entirely reader-friendly and somewhat unappealing, and rather use some "case statement", where I condition on the characters in the macro argument, one by one. The [`boolexpr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/boolexpr) provides such a `switch` environment, but I'm not sure how to extend it to work in the way I want to.

Comment: Try `parser` module of `pgf` package. It defines a finite state machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have implemented character or token parsers like this in my `tikz-timing`, `collcell` and the `ydoc` packages. They are all available under https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/ and on CTAN, of course.
Basically you are either use `\futurelet` or a macro argument (`#1`) to read the next token or character and branch accordantly, then call your input collection macro recursively.

In `collcell` I added a case statement for tokens which could be changed to take a character instead. The current syntax is:

```
\cc@case
   <token>{<code>}
   <token>{<code>}
   <token>{<code>}
   <token>{<code>}
\endcc@case
```

where the token was read before using `\futurelet\collect@cell@lettoken\next`.
See [the source code of the case statement](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/collcell/src/08f6a3561ee0/collcell.dtx#cl-436) for more details.

In `ydoc` I started with a large `\ifcase` statement but then changed it to a *look-up table*-like feature: There is one macro define for every input character, e.g. `\@namedef{mypkg@char@<char>}{<code for this character>}`, and then the parser macro only need to read the next character and use `\@nameuse{mypkg@char@#1}` (or `\csname` directly). As long you don't have any special tokens like `{`, `}` and spaces this works fine. Otherwise you need to use `\futurelet`/`\@ifnextchar` before to check for these first.

It is also possible to always use tokens with `\futurelet` and use `\meaning` to build the macro names, i.e. `\@nameuse{mypkg@char@\meaning\@let@token}`. This works with all tokens, normal or special. The handler macro should then remove the token from the input stream.

A simply character-by-character parser based on this looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{%
    \@mymacro#1\@nnil
}
\def\@mymacro#1{%
    \ifx\@nnil#1\relax\else
        \@nameuse{mymacro@char@#1\expandafter}%
    \fi
}
\def\defcharcode#1{%
    \@namedef{mymacro@char@#1}%
}
\defcharcode{1}{%
    (1)
    \@mymacro
}
\defcharcode{j}{%
    (j)
    \@mymacro
}
\defcharcode{q}#1{% reads further character!
    (q#1)
    \@mymacro
}
\defcharcode{.}{%
    (.)
    \@mymacro
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mymacro{1jq4...}

\end{document}
```

This prints: `(1) (j) (q4) (.) (.) (.)`.

The recursive call is placed in every character handler so that there is nothing after it so that it can read further input character if required.

Comment: How would you extend the last MWE to incorporate an "else" to the "case" statement? I'm thinking to check whether `mymacro@char@#1` exists, but not sure how.

Comment: Withe e-TeX `\ifcsname mymacro@char@#1\endcsname \@nameuse{mymacro@char@#1\expandafter} \else <else> \fi`, otherwise `\expandafter\ifx\csname mymacro@char@#1\endcsname\relax <else> \else \@nameuse{mymacro@char@#1\expandafter}\fi`.